# Describe the kernel, and determine whether the given vector space linear transformation is invertible:

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be the vector space of all functions mapping $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$

$T:F\rightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $T(f)=f(-4)$

---

$ker(T)=$ {$f\in F|f(-4)=0$}, by definition of kernel.

To prove that $T$ is invertible, we have to show that $T$ is one-to-one and onto. However, I never really understand how to prove onto (although I did understand the concept). So, I didn't know how to continue from here.

Comment: What is $F$?  Please clarify.

Comment: And what is $F$, mylord?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the post.

Comment: $T$ is not invertible. The dimension of $F$ is infinite, while the dimension of $\mathbb{R}$ is 1. If it were invertible that would mean that you could reconstruct a function $f$ by knowing only $f(-4)$, which is clearly false.

Comment: Notice that $T$ is a non-zero linear form. It is onto but clearly not one to one since $\dim F > 2$ and $\dim ker(T) = \dim F-1\neq 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that $T$ is onto, let $a\in\Bbb R$ and let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=a$. Then $T(f)=f(-4)=a$. Hence $T$ is onto.

To see that $T$ is not one-to-one, let $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be defined by
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= 0 &
g(x) &= 4+x
\end{align*}
Then $f\neq g$ since $f(0)=0\neq 4=g(0)$. However,
$$
T(f)=f(-4)=0=4-4=g(-4)=T(g)
$$
Hence $T$ is *not* one-to-one. Consequently, $T$ is not invertible.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, this makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is not invertible. If it were one could reconstruct a function from its value at a single point, $-4$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that a given function is onto, you need to prove that every element of the codomain is the output of the function for some input, so in this case that means you're proving that $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}\ \exists f \in F : f(-4) = y$. So if you were given a random real number, could you construct (or at least prove the existence of) a function in F that takes that real number as its value at -4?

On the other side of the fence, you also need to prove that $T$ is one-to-one, which means that each valid output in $\mathbb{R}$ comes from only one possible input in $F$. If there are two functions that give the same output, then you haven't got a one-to-one transformation. (Does the kernel contain more than one element?)

Comment: I can see that there exists more than one function in $ker(F)$, but I don't know how to write it in mathematical proof. I think it would have to do with the fact that $F$ is an infinitely generated vector space, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why not just give a counterexample or two? For example, "$f_1(x) = -4$ and $f_2(x) = x-4$ are different functions (insert quick proof if necessary) but are both in the kernel (insert quick proof), therefore ..."